# How to realize a hash function H:{0,1}* × G × {0,1}* -> Zq ？

Tags: hash

I read papers about cloud storage data integrity audit, which needs PBC library and GMP library.

The author define encryption hash function  $H:\{0,1\}^* \times G \times \{0,1\}^* \to \Bbb Z_q$, used as $H(ID,R,RN) \bmod q$, $G$ is a cyclic multiplicative group with order $q$ ,$q$ is a large prime, $R, ID,RN$ are elements of $G$.

I don't know how to compute $H(ID,R,RN) \bmod q$ ,they may multiply or do exponent arithmetic ?or use hash function like SHA1 ? How can I construct this function?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. When someone asked about some read papers, usually we want the links and maybe a little summary of them so that your question can be correctly answerable. Also, in our site we have $\LaTeX / MathJax$ is enables. I've edited some. Note hash functions are not encryption. Maybe you want to say. cryptographic hash function?

Answer (score 5):

If elements $R$ of $G$ can uniquely be expressed as a bitstring $\overline R$ (e.g. by taking the two components in a finite field of the affine coordinates of $R$, each uniquely representable as a fixed-size bitstring, and these are concatenated to form $\overline R$), then it is easy to construct a generic hash $H:\{0,1\}^* \times G \times \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb Z_q$ from a standard $b$-bit hash $F:\{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^b$, say SHA-512 with $b=512$, as follows:

- $h\gets F\big(F(\text{ID})\mathbin\|F(\overline R)\mathbin\|F(\text{RN})\big)$, which is a hash of $(\text{ID},R,\text{RN})$ in the set $\{0,1\}^b$
- if $\log_2q>b/2\,$, expand $h$ as follows:

  - $g\gets h$
  - for $i$ from $1$ to $\big\lceil(\log_2q-b/2)/b\big\rceil\,$

    - $h\gets h\mathbin\|F(g\mathbin\|\overline i)\,$, where $\overline i$ is a bitstring uniquely representing the integer $i\,$ (e.g. encoding $i$ in big-endian base 256 as a minimal number of bytes, then converted to binary)
- $r\gets \underline h\bmod q\,$, where $\underline h$ is the integer coded by the bitstring $h$ per big-endian binary

The result $r$ is the desired hash of $(\text{ID},R,\text{RN})$ in the set $\mathbb Z_q$.

This hash has nearly the same security as $F$ or an ideal hash in $\mathbb Z_q$, whichever is lower. Argument (or lack of a reference), under a model of the hash $F$ as a random oracle (and any security reduction is is with respect to that):

- The step "$h\gets F\big(F(\text{ID})\mathbin\|F(\overline R)\mathbin\|F(\text{RN})\big)$" is a generic composition of hashes, in order to hash multiple inputs of variable size (while maintaining collision resistance contrary to mere concatenation), and allowing a security reduction.
- The step "if $\log_2q>b/2\,$, expand $h$" does that essentially as in [MGF1](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=50), again allowing a security reduction.
- The step "$r\gets \underline h\bmod q\,$" insures the output is in the desired range. It create a bias towards low values, but since at least $b/2$ bits are discarded this bias is low, and it's possible to upper-bound the advantage a distinguisher can obtain.

Comment: Can you please link a paper that estimates the security of H?

Comment: @Mikhail Kudinov: sorry I don't have a reference. I have added a security argument, and will think about making it more rigorous; but don't hold your breath.

Comment: That last step makes assumptions about F beyond collision resistance.

Comment: @Maeher: Agreed in full. I put myself "under a model of the hash $F$ as a random oracle", and any later "security reduction" is w.r.t. that [update: added that to the answer]. My "while maintaining collision resistance" is not meant as an intermediary step in a proof (rather, as a rationale for multiple hashes), and the whole thing is not intended to be a proper proof.

Comment: Sure, for a random oracle that should work.